# @Html.TextAreaFor how to display only 2 rows and disable scroll bar

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, textarea

Does anyone knows how to style TextAreaFor to display only 2 rows of text instead showing default 4 or 5 even if I define to display only 2 no matter which way? I would be also grateful if anyone tell how to hide scroll bars.

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AdkOgAvstandCom,new { cols = 10, rows = 2 })
```

This code works fine if you want to increase number of rows however if you want to narrow them it just ignores new values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BG100 is on to something. Assuming your original code generates a html `<textarea>` with a rows attribute set to "2", all you need to disable scrollbars is;

**css**

```
textarea {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/rpnmm/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AdkOgAvstandCom, new { style = "height: 2em; overflow: hidden;" })
```

Comment: I don't think you would need the height: 2em; if the rows attribute is set to 2. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/rpnmm/

Comment: The scroll bar is gone however height settings are not applied, it still shows 4 rows both in IE and Chrome

Comment: Also, the default line height is approximately 1.2 (depending on the font choice), so if you want two lines, you'll get closer with `height: 2.4em`

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in above answer that scrollbars can be removed by `overflow:hidden` but if you want to restrict user to stick within your desired number of rows only then you can try this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharshuklaa/qL7ec058/).

Comment: @downvoter: Any comments or reason why you have downvoted my answer?